# Calling an action using Ajax URL in Struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am trying to connect to my action class by using URL as below in Ajax. But its not going into my action class and even it is not showing the selected value by using `$("#selectedCountry").val()`.

```
function getstates(){           
    alert($("#selectedCountry").val());         
    $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url  : "/ThirdTask/selectstate.action",
      dataType : 'text',
      data : "name="+$("#selectedCountry").val(),
      success : function(){
        $('statesdivid').html();
      },
      error : alert("No values found..!!")
    });         
}
```

**My JSP code as follows:**

```
<s:select  name="selectedCountry"  list="{'india','china'}"  onclick="getstates();"/></div>
<div id="statesdivid">
<s:if test="%{#request.selectedstatenames != null}"> 
<s:select list="#request.selectedstatenames" name="selectedState">
</s:select>
</s:if>
</div>
```

**My `struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="selectstate.action" class="com.thirdtask.actions.SelectAction" method="selectstate">
 <result name="success">selecttag.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

Comment: You don't have an element with `selectedCountry` id.

Comment: Did you try a doubleselect, either struts or jQuery?

Comment: Even i tried by keeping selectedCountry ID ,but no result @ Aleksandr M

Comment: NO i haven't tried. I just started learning struts a week ago. @ Roman C

Comment: First, you need to write an action you want to connect to. After that map it to the defined URL. Test it by entering in the browser. Then explain what it not working, if you have errors you could post a stacktrace with the root cause.

Comment: when i am trying to connect by using FORM ACTION/ ACTION TAG its going into my action class but when am trying by using ajax its not going to class

Comment: What is the `struts.xml` or how the action is mapped?

Comment: <action name="selectstate.action" class="com.thirdtask.actions.SelectAction" method="selectstate">
  <result name="success">selecttag.jsp</result>
  </action>

Comment: You have incorrect configuration. Also don't post a code in comments, edit your question and add details.

Comment: Am new to stackoverflow ..so i dont know about that..Thanks for the info. Incorrect Configuration is about..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To map an action to the method you should do something like

```
<action name="selectstate" class="com.thirdtask.actions.SelectAction" method="selectstate">
  <result>/selecttag.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

action name should be without action extension and result by default is named "success", the path to JSP should be absolute here.

Calling ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url  : "<s:url action='selectstate'/>",
    dataType : 'text/javascript',
    data : {'name' : $("#selectedCountry").text()},
    success : function(result){
      if (result != null && result.length > 0){
        $("statesdivid").html(result);
      }
    },
    error : function(xhr, errmsg) {alert("No values found..!!");}
});
```